# Point System - localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, system, local-storage

I am creating a Point System, and once people get enough points, they can use some of the points to get cool features on my site. The using points part (detracting points each time the user gets something with their points) of the code is not working. Here is my jQuery for the Point System:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#curren').delay(200).animate({'top' : '-1px'},1500);
if (localStorage.points222){
  localStorage.points222=Number(localStorage.points222) +5;
}
else{
  localStorage.points222=0;
}
function buy5(){
  if (localStorage.points222){
  localStorage.points222=Number(localStorage.points222) -5;
}
else{
  localStorage.points222=0;
}
} 
   $('#point_counter').html(localStorage.points222);

if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 1){
   $('#point_name').html("1");
   $('#take').fadeIn();
}
else{
   $('#take').fadeOut();
} 
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 500){
   $('#point_name').html("2");
}
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 1000){
   $('#point_name').html("3");
}

if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 2000){
   $('#point_name').html("4");
}
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 5000){
   $('#point_name').html("5");
}
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 10000){
   $('#point_name').html("6");
}
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 20000){
   $('#point_name').html("7");
}
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="curren">
  Your Current Level: <b><span id="point_name"></span></b><br>
  Points: <b><span id="point_counter"></span></b>
  <span style="FLOAT:right;cursor:pointer;display:none;" id="take" onclick="buy5()">-5</span>
</div>
```

If you need more information on how the code is setup, please let me know.

Comment: I don't believe `localStorage.points222` is a supported syntax for creating and getting local storage information. You need to do `localStorage.getItem('key')`
 or `localStorage['key']`. In addition, are you using a browser that supports that?

Comment: @Tejs... You don't get it....the system works. Just not the taking points away part! Read correctly....and pay attention!

Comment: `The Buying points part of the code is not working.` - This is what you posted. Perhaps you can be more descriptive of the problem then?

Comment: @Tejs `localStorage.keyValueName` does work as does `localStorage["keyValueName"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you never update the displayed amount of points. You misplaced a line.

The value in `localStorage` is indeed decreased by 5 every time a user clicks on the `<span>` and `buy5()` is called, **but** .. you never update the displayed value of points. In other words, the line..

```
$('#point_counter').html(localStorage.points222);
```

.. should be **inside the definition of** `buy5`, when right now it is one bracket too far. It's not being called at the end of every `buy5()`, instead it's called just once, as part of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Even if I do:  



function buy5(){
if (localStorage.points222){
  localStorage.points222=Number(localStorage.points222) -5;
}
    $('#point_counter').html(localStorage.points222);
}

Its not working.